# has_one and has_many relationships to the SAME object type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism, has-many, has-one

I'm writing a website using Ruby on Rails and I have a number of polymorphic relationships but I want two particular relationships that are:

```
A has_one C
B has_many C
```

When I generate the polymorphic code for C using Rails it seems that the has_one A/C relationship expects functions of form:

```
A.C... e.g.
@c = @poly.c.find(params[:id])
```

whilst the has_many B/C relationship expects functions of form

```
B.Cs... ** Note the plural for B **
@c = @poly.cs.find(params[:id])
```

So is there a way to do what I want or do I have to make the A/C relationship has_many and add additional checking to ensure that it acts like has_one?

Comment: To help others better understand your question, please use real world examples instead of using `A`, and `C`.

Comment: You can use polymorphism on 1-1, 1-many and many-to-many relations. Its very unclear what you are actually trying to achieve. Can you try to focus less on how you think it should be done and more on describing the problem at hand?

Comment: I am creating some objects to hold geocode points (latitude and longitute).  They will be associated either with an address, where there will be a one-to-one relationship or an area, where there will be a one-to-many with the points defining the area.  I have other uses for them but they'll obviously be one-to-one or one-to-many.

Comment: Umm. Starting to think that I've wandered so far into the woods that I can't see the trees here.  Where I only require one point, for example the address, I might just as well make the latitude and longitude part of the address object.  This feels reasonable and then means that I can leave the geocodes to be has_many from those objects that need >=1 of them.